# How to delete a specific value from a vector?

Tags: c++, vector

Basically, I have a vector of a struct. I'm making the game Monopoly and I have a vector of a playerStruct. I have an option for a player to leave the game. However, I don't know how to delete any player as the vector shrinks. For example I have 3 players

```
Players 0,1,2
```

And I use the erase function,

```
erase(vect.begin()+turnNumber);
```

I first erase player 0 which is just `erase(vect.begin()+0)` and erases the first element. However, if I try to erase player 1 by calling `erase(vect.begin()+1)`, I end up erasing player 2 as the vector has shrunk to a size of 2.

**How do I erase a player at any point while the vector decreases? I can't seem to think of a formula `erase(vect.begin()+(a number))` to be able to erase any player from the game without erasing another player that isn't meant to be erased.**
Thank you.

Comment: [`std::remove_if()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) maybe? What does _TDLR_ mean BTW?

Comment: you could use `std::set`

Comment: Do you identify players by their index in the vector If yes, why? If not, search by that identification and then delete the corresponding index.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is a combination of:

- The index of an object in the vector identifies the player with witch it's associated
- The vector can change (decrease) in size, but players' IDs do not change

Thus after any change to the vector, indexing it by a player's ID is no longer valid.

---

You could try using a [`std::map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/?kw=map) or [`std::unordered_map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/) instead, which would map player number to `Player`. You could then call `erase()` on the map with the player(s) you want to remove.

---

If you *must* use a `std::vector`, you would need to have your `Player` store the player's ID. You could then search through the vector for the player you want to remove without using vector indices.

**Edit**

As an example, if we assume your struct looks something like:

```
struct Player {
    int id;
    // ...other members
};
```

and you have `vector<Player> players`, you could erase player `n` with [`std::remove_if`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_if/) as such:

```
auto iter = remove_if(players.begin(), players.end(), [&](Player const & player) {
    return player.id == n;
});
players.erase(iter, players.end());
```

Comment: How would I remove vector by a player's ID? Each player has their own int ID.

Comment: Edited with an example using `std::remove_if`

Answer (score 0):

Erase backwards, from last to first.